# Cannot insert into DynamoDB table from Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, noclassdeffounderror

I'm getting the following error when I run my lambda function that's supposed to put an an item into my DynamoDB table.

```json
      "errorMessage": "com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder",
      "errorType": "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError",
      "stackTrace": [
        "dao.EventDAO.insertEvent(EventDAO.java:15)",
        "service.PostEventService.postEvent(PostEventService.java:12)",
        "handler.PostEventHandler.handle(PostEventHandler.java:11)",
        "java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)",
        "java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)",
        "java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)",
        "java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)"
      ]
```

And here is my code that is trying to insert into the table:

```java
    package dao;
    
    import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB;
    import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder;
    import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.DynamoDB;
    import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Item;
    import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.PutItemOutcome;
    import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Table;
    import request.PostEventRequest;
    import response.PostEventResponse;
    
    public class EventDAO {
    
        public PostEventResponse insertEvent(PostEventRequest request) {
            AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().build();
            DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);
            Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("Event");
            PostEventResponse response = new PostEventResponse();
    
            // Build the item
            Item item = new Item()
                    .withPrimaryKey("eventId", request.eventId)
                    .withString("username", request.username)
                    .withString("image", request.image)
                    .withString("description", request.description)
                    .withString("time", request.time);
    
            // Write the item to the table
            PutItemOutcome outcome = table.putItem(item);
    
            return response;
        }
    }
```

and here's my pom.xml as i suspect this may be important:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.327</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
        <properties>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        </properties>
    
        <groupId>earnshawsfinest</groupId>
        <artifactId>rally-backend</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </project>
```

For some reason when it's in lambda it doesn't recognize the AmazonDynamoDbClientBuilder class, even though in my project in IntelliJ it is there and important. My IntelliJ project builds with no problem, and it exports a jar (with modules and dependencies) that I upload to lambda. The lambda will work just fine if I take out the DynamoDB stuff.

I feel like I'm maybe I'm missing some download or import somewhere but I don't know what. I've followed all sorts of tutorials from amazon, and I've even done this before but I didn't run into this problem. Any help? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

By default the dependencies are not bundled inside the jar file. You need to do that or provide them in a separate lambda layer

Check the link [Building a deployment package with Maven](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-package.html) and see using the `maven-shade-plugin`, that should build all the dependencies inside the target jar file.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```